# java.sql.Date and java.sql.Time to org.joda.time.DateTime

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, jodatime

As the question title says,

I have `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Time` as input

Now I want to convert them to a `DateTime` object, but since the getDay, getYear etc. methods are deprecated I can't figure out how to combine the two...

Comment: Can you get a `long` from the sql data types, and use that to construct a joda DateTime?

Comment: I can get a long from both, but adding them together doesnt do the job...

Comment: What's the idea behind adding these types? They both represent a time since the Epoch.

Comment: You can just pass your `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Time` to the constructor of Joda's `DateTime`, but it sounds like you want more than just that. What do you mean exactly by "adding them together"?

Comment: It sounds like his date is stored in one column, and the time is stored in a separate column in his database. Luc, can u explain?

Comment: Yes, the date and time are stored in different columns, but for my output I need a "beginDateTime" and an "endDateTime" where begin contains the date + startTime and end contains date + endTime

Comment: @Luc - Just check my answer. See if that helps your cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just see if this does the trick for you.

```
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Prints 2013-03-08
Time time = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Prints 15:40:33

String myDate = date + " " + time;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
try {
    utilDate = sdf.parse(myDate); // You get a Java Util Date object(Fri Mar 08 15:40:33 IST 2013)
} catch (ParseException pe) {
   // TODO something.
}

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(utilDate); // You get your JODA object.
```

Comment: Using formatting to construct a Date is inefficient, and ignores joda time's rich API. Why not simply combine a LocalDate and LocalTime into a DateTime?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a DateTime object from the date and add a Duration object to that DateTime object, resulting in a single object whcih is the Date + Time instant in time represented by your input.

Something like the following:

```
Date d = //your Date
Time t = //your time

DateTime result = new DateTime(d).plus(t.getTime());
```

This will result in an Immutable object representing the instant you want....I I understood your question correctly and what you are after is a way of "adding" two different classes representing time.

Answer (score 0):

Just do some tricks on java.sql.Time: calculate the duration. java.sql.Time set date components to January 1, 1970 implicitly.

```
    java.sql.Date epoch = new Date(70, 0, 1);
    java.sql.Date date = new Date(113, 2, 8);
    java.sql.Time time = new Time(1, 1, 1);
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(date.getTime())
            .plus(time.getTime() - epoch.getTime());
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(time);
    System.out.println(dt);
```